# Show and hide the footer element when scrolling to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I have a structure like this:
[image]

As you can see, I have a fixed `nav-bar` at the top of the page and a drop down sidebar. Then I have a `<div>` element with `content` id.

Inside this `<div>` element I have some content, and finally, I have a `<div>` with a fixed position to the bottom of the page.

What I want is to hide the bottom div when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

I have tried this but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
    $('div#content').scroll(function () {
        var fixedBottom = $("#dialog-button-bar");
        if ($('div#content').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
            fixedBottom.css("opacity", 0 );
        } else {
            fixedBottom.css("opacity", 1 );
        }
    });
```

I hope to someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one because `scrollTop()` and `height()` jQuery methods change their returned value when adding and removing an HTML element.

One way of doing this is by defining a boolean variable that will help avoid the document height to be changed when adding the footer. And so, by doing this is possible to create an if statement that will change the CSS attribute `display` according to the scroll position.

```js
let footerVisible = false;
var docHeight = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
   if(footerVisible == false){docHeight = $(document).height()}
   
   if(scrollPos >= docHeight){
    footerVisible = true;
    $('.footer').css('display', 'block');
   }else if(scrollPos <= docHeight){
    footerVisible = false;
    $('.footer').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

```css
*{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;color:white;text-align:center}
.nav{
  background: #00A19D;
  height:60px;
}
.content{
  background: #FFF8E5;
  height:1500px;
}
.footer{
  background: #345B63;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='nav'><br><h1>Nav</h1></section>
<section class='content'></section>
<section class='footer'><br><h1>Magical Footer</h1></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the scollTop to the height constantly, would this not always make the if statement true, as the height+some value is always bigger than the divs height. Try comparing the documents height to the scrollTop and not the divs height

Comment: Like this? `if ($('div#content').height() <= $('div#content').scrollTop())`

Comment: @martibellot no, ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).height()) something like that should work, as you are comparing your amount of scroll to the height of the window

Comment: $(window).scrollTop() is allways 0 because the scroll is in the div#content

Comment: @martibellot oh my bad, I misunderstood that part, then you should be able to say ($('div#content').scrollTop() >= $('div#content').height()) then, comparing the scroll to the  height, instead of the height to the scroll, if that makes sense?